# Cannot find any coverage data (.coverage or .coveragexml) files. Check test run details for possible errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate and I cannot get code coverage data. All of my unit tests pass, and I edited the Local.testsettings file to enable code coverage and configured it to reference the dll of my project. Also the active test setting is set to Local.testsettings and not TracAndTestImpact.testsettings.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem.  I configured my .testsettings to include code coverage as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504821(VS.100).aspx

What I was doing wrong is that I was running the test by pressing F5 in Visual Studio.

What I needed to do was double-click the ".vsmdi" file, which will open the "Test List Editor".  Then I clicked the "Run Tests in Current Context" - (Ctrl+R, T) in the Test Code command bar. Code Coverage worked after that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, the link helped me out. Needed to select Code Coverage and click the Configure button and select the assembly to perform code coverage on.

Comment: If it helps anyone else, I had code coverage set, selected the dll's I wanted and it still dodn't work until I did as Garry suggests with the VSMDI file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you still have this problem, but I had a similar issue and I've managed to fix it. I removed the testrunconfig file from my solution folder. Then added it back in and it came up with the settings dialog box, where I enabled the code coverage. Then I double clicked on code coverage and it came up with a list of dlls and I selected the ones that I needed. It saved the settings correctly and now when I run my tests, I can see the results in code coverage.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble getting this to work until I found out that the test project must use the 4.0 .NET Framework (or later).

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the test from the `test list` rather than the `testresults` window and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above, and in fact nothing worked until ... I restarted Visual Studio.